# c++ illegal indirection array and pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int n, char** args)
{
        int x[]= {2};
        int y[]= {8};
        int *p = x;
        int *q = y;

        printf("0x%x 0x%x\n", x, *x);
        printf("0x%x 0x%x\n", p, **p);
        printf("0x%x 0x%x\n", y, *y);
        printf("0x%x 0x%x\n", q, **q);
        printf("0x%x \n", &p);
        printf("0x%x \n", &q);
        system("pause");
}
```

idk whyit shows illegal indirection, while the question is like this ,

Introduce int variables x and y and int* pointer variables p and q. Set x to 2, y to 8, p to the address of x, 
and q to the address of y. Then print the following information :

"1.  The address of x and the value of x.
2.  The value of p and the value of *p.
3.  The address of y and the value of y.
4.  The value of q and the value of *q.
5.  The address of p (not its contents!).
6.  The address of q (not its contents!)."

what's wrong with my code please help me :((

Comment: You're lacking basic understanding of C++'s type system. If you have `int m` then it is not valid to write `*m;` . For the same reason, if you have `int *p` it is not valid to write `**p`.

Comment: Your code does not match your text; it should be `int x = 2;` and `int y = 8;`.  For the rest of the program you will need to use the address-of operator, `&` .

Comment: I can see errors--but what error messages are you getting and you are complaining about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
#include <stdio.h>
 #include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
int main(int n, char** args) 
{ int x= 2; 
int y= 8;
int *p = &x; 
int *q = &y; 
printf("0x%x 0x%u\n", &x,x);
printf("0x%x 0x%u\n", p, *p);   
printf("0x%x 0x%u\n", &y, y); 
printf("0x%x 0x%u\n", q, *q);
printf("0x%x \n", &p);
printf("0x%x \n", &q); 
system("pause"); }
```